# How to create a row wise report for single person VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

kindly please help to create a report in vb.net (crystal report) as picture given belw.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fNOyy.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use field in **Details** section of crystal report to get the report for all rows of query/dataset

[Check image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DlWjT.jpg)

Comment: Thanks got it. but i still can't retrieve image from access database to crystal report.

Comment: Do you have file path in access database

Comment: You have an Image in Access database or path of image in Access database?

Comment: i have file path in access database. like D:\CMS\Images\img1.jpg

Comment: Use a conditional formula to dynamically change the location of a report’s image.

Add an image to the report (Insert | Picture). This image will act as a placeholder.  Ensure that the placeholder is the same size as the one that will be dynamically loaded, otherwise the image will be scaled.
Change the image’s Graphic Location:
right click image
select Format Graphic…
select Picture tab
click the conditional-formula button (looks like x+2)
set the formula’s text to the name of the formula or parameter field that will contain the image’s URL
save the formula and click the OK button